# Getting clicked Item object using XAML databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, click

I am binding my ListBox to an items collection, which contains instances of my Item's class.

This part works as expected. The problem i'm having is accessing the clicked ListBox items `item` instance. I have included the full example and the relevant XAML.

I have also included an example of how I would like to access the `Item` instance inside the `listBoxItems_PreviewMouseDown` event handler.

I assume i'm missing something obvious, but the code crashes when I click an item. Am I missing another binding to glue all of this together?

Thank you

**Code behind**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Item class
        internal class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public Item(string name = null)
            {
                this.Name = name;
            }

            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string ImagePath { get; set; }
            public string SomeString { get; set; }
            public int SomeInt { get; set; }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }

        // Item collection
        ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsCollection;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Initialize the items collection
            this.ItemsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Item newItem = new Item
                    {
                        Name = "test " + i,
                        ImagePath = @"Images\" + i + ".jpg",
                        SomeString = "example" + i,
                        SomeInt = i,
                    };

                    // Add the new item to the collection
                    this.ItemsCollection.Add(newItem);
                }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
            }

            // Set the items source
            this.listBoxItems.ItemsSource = this.ItemsCollection;
        }

        // Handle mouse down events on listbox items
        private void listBoxItems_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Ideally, i'd like to do something like this
            Item item = sender as Item;

            // So then I could do for example
            Console.WriteLine(@"Clicked item SomeString: {0}, SomeInt {1}", item.SomeString, item.SomeInt);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```xml
<userControls:MyListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" PreviewMouseDown="listBoxItems_PreviewMouseDown">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="200" Height="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</userControls:MyListBox>
```

Comment: In your case sender will be List, so cast sender to List. Take out its selected item. cast it to ListItem and cast its `DataContext` to `Item` type.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal If i'm casting sender to List<item> how do I retrieve the selected item?

Comment: My bad. `sender` would be `ListBox`, so cast sender to ListBox. Take out its selected item. Cast that to `ListItem` and cast its `DataContext` to `Item` type.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal So you mean something like this? https://gist.github.com/DannyGlover/bbf2bf5900510445abf12e8a55854cd8  - It still crashes, so perhaps i'm interpreting you incorrectly. Thanks for the help thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the accepted answer, alternatively you can bind the `PreviewMouseDown` event directly to the `ListBoxItem`.

In that case the **XAML** can be (emphasis on the added `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` node):

```xml
<userControls:MyListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" PreviewMouseDown="listBoxItems_PreviewMouseDown">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="200" Height="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="listBoxItems_PreviewMouseDown" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</userControls:MyListBox>
```

And the **handler**:

```
    // Handle mouse down events on listbox items
    private void listBoxItems_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        // Ideally, i'd like to do something like this
        Item item = (sender as ListBoxItem).DataContext as Item;

        // So then I could do for example
        Console.WriteLine(@"Clicked item SomeString: {0}, SomeInt {1}", item.SomeString, item.SomeInt);
    }
```

Comment: This answer is even better than the previous one, as it results in cleaner (imho) code behind. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `OriginalSource` of the event and examine its `DataContext`:

```
var item = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement)?.DataContext as Item;
if (item != null) { /* Do something with item... */ }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Makes a lot more sense now (the problem and the solution). Thank you very much.